# Preserve Left to Right Order of Columns Across Browsers

Tags: javascript, css

We are using MVC, bootstrap, and jsGrid to display data retrieved from a linq query. I used Google Chrome and Opera to develop the page. In the cshtml I list the columns in the order I want. So, Name, ID, AgreementId, DateStart, etc. This worked fine in my two browsers. In Firefox, IE, and Edge, however, the order of columns is reversed! How do I ensure the columns are always in the order I want?

Comment: Which locale (`grid.locale-XX.js`) and which options of jqGrid you use (especially `direction` option)? Which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7). You wrote about Edge, thus I suppose that you tested on Windows 10. Some screenshorts which shows the problem could be helpful.

Comment: Sorry, wrong tag. Not using jqGrid, using <u>js</u>Grid. v.1.4.1.

Comment: Sorry, but it's absolutely another product and thus I can't help you. I suppose that you use https://github.com/tabalinas/jsgrid. There are one more jqgrid: https://github.com/openpsa/jsgrid which is fork of jqGrid, but it uses another version numbers.